# Representing a Number as the Sum of Powers of Form $k^k$.

Tags: number-theory, information-theory, power-towers, bit-strings

So I was wondering if it would be useful to instead of writing a number in base $2$ or $3$, we use functions in general as bases. So like writing it as the sum of squares or other increasing functions. So for a number $N$, its base $f(n)$ representation could be found basically in the same way that you would find the base $2$ representation of $N$. The representation could be written as a "string" of characters and each character could be written in its binary representation. For example, $8153 = [1000][1][101][11]$ which took $10$ bits to write out. I wanted to see if there was a function that would dramatically reduce the number of bits required to store a number.

Comment: You'll need to include the brackets in your bit count because, for example, $91 = [1001][1] = [100][11]=43$ is not true.  But in general if you have $n$ bits, you can only specify between $2^n$ values.  This is because the set of $n$ bit binary sequences is isomorphic to the integers $1$ to $2^n$, and each integer can correspond to one number that you want to represent.

Comment: The way I found the upper bound was because the highest character you can have for some place value n is n^n/((n-1)^n-1) - 1, you get that the max # of bits is the summation of the log2 ( ceil((n^n/((n-1)^n-1) - 1)) from n=1 to ceil(f^-1(N)). This is roughly the summation of log2(n^n/(n-1)^n-1) from n=1 to ceil(f^-1(N)). But this is a telescoping sum that ends up being log2(f(f^-1(N)) = log2(N).

Comment: I think my reasoning is a bit off but it still looks like base n^n representation is on average, more efficient than base 2.

Comment: I agree with you on the brackets but I think if you use the function f(x) = x^x, you can on average, use less bits than if you just use binary. The base n^n representation of 50,000 for example is 110803 which would be written as [1][1][0][1000][0][11] which takes up 10 bits. On the other hand, the base 2 representation takes up 16 bits. In the worst case scenario, I think the base n^n representation takes up log2(N).

Comment: Oh wait nm I didn't properly read what you said about the brackets. In that case,  the worst case is definitely worse than log2(N). But I think you can get away with not putting brackets around the single character bits and have whatever's reading the string only group them when it sees a bracket. In that case, the base n^n representation for 50,000 is 14 bits.

Comment: But on average and for big N, it probably will be worse than base 2.

Comment: Using 14 bits, can you write all numbers between 1 and 50,000?  You cannot, because there are only 16,384 binary strings of length 14.  So you can represent at most 16,384 different numbers.  You might be able to get some high ones, but there will definitely be gaps.  So you're right it will be worse than base 2 on average.  but definitely worth thinking about when it could be advantageous.  Maybe if we know something a priori about the numbers we are trying to encode.